# MONGOOSE DeprecationWarning Mongoose and MongoParseError mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect with mongoDB Atlas
here is the code from my .env file copied from Atlast connection string
(note:name and password madeup, autogenerated password, username all letters no numbers or special characters)
DATABASE_URI=mongodb+srv://databasename:hjfksf432FDS34
@cluster0.6mxghis.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

I got this warning and error

```
(node:9864) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
MongoParseError: mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number
    at new ConnectionString (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:146:23)
    at parseOptions (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:200:17)
    at new MongoClient (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:45:63)
    at C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:802:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:799:19)
    at C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:417:10
    at C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
MongoParseError: mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number
    at new ConnectionString (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:146:23)
    at parseOptions (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:200:17)
    at new MongoClient (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:45:63)
    at C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:802:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:799:19)
    at C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:417:10
    at C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\pokahontas\New folder\demo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause for this is the username or password contain one of the characters `: / ? # [ ] @`.

[Percent-encode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) any such characters.

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP for a quick-reference table